# How do I force set the user context without a key value store or wallet?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-java

For testing purposes, I already have the public key + private key + certificate on hand (can just hardcode it), and I can set up the CA through the connection profile, but how would I invoke a transaction without setting up the filesystem key value store/wallet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `InMemoryWallet` class - see https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/master/module-fabric-network.InMemoryWallet.html

example:

```
 const credPath = '/home/demo/mynetwork/crypto-material/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/User1@org1.example.com/msp';
 const cert = fs.readFileSync(credPath + '/cert.pem').toString();
 const key = fs.readFileSync(credPath + '/key.pem').toString();
 const inMemoryWallet = new InMemoryWallet();
 await inMemoryWallet.import('admin', X509WalletMixin.createIdentity('Org1MSP', cert, key));
```

or check out the [integration test scripts for Fabric Node SDK](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-node/blob/release-1.4/test/typescript/integration/network-e2e/invoke.ts#L49)